# How to run Robot class commands with selenium before browser page load

Tags: selenium, browser, loading, pageload

I am trying to automate a page which has an Active directory authentication. I am using Robot class to pass the user/Password which is not working.

I tried debugging and it seems like the Robot class commands are not working because the page is still loading in the background when the AD Authentication window pops up.
Same code works fine when I replace the URL with Google.com portal.
Request your help, Thanks.

Here's the code...

```
    driver.get("https://www.mypageurl.com");    
    //driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    //none of the below line of codes are not executed for mypageurl but works for Google
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);  

    //Code to enter username
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);  

    //Code to enter password
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript executor to wait for page to load.Please see below link hope this help you.

https://www.testingexcellence.com/webdriver-wait-page-load-example-java/